# В С++ нужен любой код но с использованием след. Функций:Functrion,Array,string,pointer

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, функции, указатели

Function
String 
Array 
Pointer

Answer (score 5):

Люди, я все же отвечу, ладно? :)

Вот код, в котором использованы **функции**  `Function`, `String`, `Array`,  `Pointer`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Function(const char * s)
{
    cout << s;
}

void Array(const char * s)
{
    Function(s);
}

const char * String(int i)
{
    return i ? "Hello" : "World";
}

const char * Pointer()
{
    return "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Array(String(1));
    Function(" ");
    Array(String(0));
    Array(Pointer());
}
```

Все, как заказано. [Код полностью рабочий](https://ideone.com/EHaBrl)...